# Simple copy procedure openCV, `Vec3b` to `Vec3f` types

Tags: c++, opencv

Practicing a little bit with openCV (I'm aware of the operator `=` overloaded) This simple program runs fine:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using cv::imread;
using cv::Mat;
using cv::namedWindow;
using cv::waitKey;
using cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE;
using cv::Vec3b;
using cv::Vec3f;

Mat myCopy(const Mat& input) {
    int n_cols = input.cols;
    int n_rows = input.rows;
    Mat output = Mat(n_rows, n_cols, input.type(), 0.0f);
    for (auto i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < n_cols; ++j) {
            Vec3b v = input.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
            output.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = v;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Copy done!" << std::endl;
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Could not open image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);
    waitKey(0);

    Mat sRGBimage = myCopy(image);
    if (!sRGBimage.data) {
        cout << "Could not copy image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", sRGBimage);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

But If I change the function

```
Mat myCopy(const Mat& input) {
        int n_cols = input.cols;
        int n_rows = input.rows;
        Mat output = Mat(n_rows, n_cols, input.type(), 0.0f);
        for (auto i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
            for (auto j = 0; j < n_cols; ++j) {
                Vec3b v = input.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
                output.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = v;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Copy done!" << std::endl;
        return output;
    }
```

With

```
Mat myCopy(const Mat& input) {
    int n_cols = input.cols;
    int n_rows = input.rows;
    Mat output = Mat(n_rows, n_cols, input.type(), 0.0f);
    for (auto i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < n_cols; ++j) {
            Vec3f v = input.at<Vec3f>(i, j);
            output.at<Vec3f>(i, j) = v;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Copy done!" << std::endl;
    return output;
}
```

It doesn't work, I have corrupted memory.
The only change is changing the `Vec3b` type with `Vec3f`.
The operation wasn't actually a copy in the beginning, was a gamma transformation of the pixels.

I assume there's some subtlety with the numeric types, can any explain what's going on?

Comment: "It doesn't work, I have corrupted memory." -- obviously. You have an array of unsigned 1 byte integers, and you're treating them as if they were 4 byte floating point values.

Comment: But what's the fix? I've tried `Mat<float>` (because apparently it's a template type) it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use a data type that corresponds to the data type of the elements. Your input `Mat` is `CV_8UC3` (3 channels of unsigned chars), so `cv::Vec3b` is the appropriate type to use with `cv::Mat::at`. If you want floating point, then either convert the whole `Mat` to `CV_32FC3`, or read out `cv:Vec3b` and convert that to floating point.

Comment: but when I load the image using `imread` the image is loaded as 3 bytes per pixel right? So in theory I should convert this to float, and then back to 3 bytes per pixel. Correct?

Comment: Yes, when you load it it's `CV_8UC3` (assuming it's colour without transparency, as in your case). Yes, you could convert whole image to float, do your transformation (perhaps using a vectorized operation, so you avoid those loops), and then convert back. | The main point is that `cv::Mat::at` does not do any conversion -- you have to parametrize it with a type that corresponds to what's actually in the `Mat`, otherwise you get nonsense (or worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes needed. You cannot initialize

```
Mat output = Mat(n_rows, n_cols, input.type(), 0.0f);
```

as `input.type()` is most likely `CV_8UC3`. Change it to

```
Mat output = Mat(n_rows, n_cols, CV_32FC3, 0.0f);
```

Later, access the input as `CV_8UC3` and output as `CV_32FC3`:

```
Vec3b v = input.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
output.at<Vec3f>(i, j)[0] = v[0];
...
```

I'm not sure if overloading `Vec` is possible.

Or you can use `input.convertTo(output,CV_32F)`.